# Starting with an onomatopoeia?

Tags: onomatopoeia

Is it okay to start with an onomatopeia and after that use an uppercase letter ?
E.g:

```
"Tum...Tum...Tum" The sound of ...
```

Comment: Hi Weslley. Is it meant to be all one sentence, or is 'The' the start of a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[E. A. Poe, in *Bells*](https://poets.org/poem/bells), uses capitalization as for standard English, e.g.

> Bells, bells, bells—
>
> From the jingling and the tinkling of the bells.